# cast_set deprecated. What’s the replacement?

Tags: open-policy-agent

I’m currently running OPA version 0.39.0, but I’m trying to upgrade to a more recent version and am getting the following issue:

```
rego_type_error: deprecated built-in function calls in expression: cast_set
```

I tried looking through the docs and release notes but don’t see anything about cast_set being deprecated. Is there a work around to continue using a deprecated function or is there a suggested replacement?

Also, is OPA following SemVer, with Major.Minor.Patch? Would expect subsequent versions after 0.39.0 to still be compatible with it since we are currently on 0.46.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not state which command you are running when you see that error. The only one that *should* produce that is `opa check --strict`, where the very purpose of the command is to check for things like unused variables, use of deprecated functions, etc... i.e. [strict mode](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/strict/).

I just tried some other commands, like `opa build` and `opa run`, and none of them seem to produce that warning - and they shouldn't.

The idiomatic way of creating a set from an array, is to use a [set comprehension](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#set-comprehensions):

```
my_arr := [1, 2, 3]
my_set := {x | x := my_arr[_]} 

my_set == {1, 2, 3}
```

We try hard to not make backwards compatibile changes in OPA, and if you're seeing this error outside of strict mode, please open an issue. A command like `opa check --strict` is however *meant* to warn about things like this, so that's going to be an obvious exception.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked in rego.v1.

Something like below:

```
interactions := [abc | some abc in list_a; abc in cast_set(list_b)]
```

can be replaced with:

```
set_b := {elem | elem = list_b[_]}
interactions := [elem | elem := list_a[_]; elem in set_b]
```

Example:

```
list_a := ["123", "456", "789"]
list_b := ["456", "999", "789"]
interactions := ["456", "789"]
```